# How to edit curl output in place?

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I am curling commands for a bash script to run an installation on my linux system and then piping it to the bash console.

```
curl -G website/bashscript.sh | sudo bash
```

However the commands I receive from curl has an added

```
echo "Rebooting"
reboot
```

at the end.

This curl and sudo command is within my own bash script I am writing for automating an installation process.

How do I remove the echo and reboot command from this text and pipe it to bash? I would rather not save it to a file, edit it, then pass it to bash since I really don't want to remove the text file afterwards.

Thanks!

Comment: `curl ... | sudo bash` is a recipe for disaster. I would never use a software that has to be installed like that.

Comment: I would recommend downloading a static copy of the script, manually modify it and don't download it each time at runtime because you  can't guarantee the remote has not changed the script.

Comment: That is the purpose, to get the updated version of the script. I agree this is sketchy and probably unsecure, but this is the only way to do it.

Comment: Who's _building_ this software? If they aspire to have customers/users at sites with sane security policies, they'll construct another way to do it. If they don't... maybe you shouldn't be using their tools.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last line, if it is the word `reboot`:

```
sed '${/^reboot$/d}'
```

The [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) syntax: [`$`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Last-line_002c-selecting) selects the last line. [`{`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-_007b_007d-command-grouping) starts a block. [`/^reboot$/`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regexp-Addresses) selects lines, which contain only the word `reboot` (`^` matches the beginning and `$` matches the end of the line). [`d`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-d-_0028delete_0029-command) deletes the line in case of a match. `}` closes the block.

Remove the last line, if it is the phrase `echo "Rebooting"`:

```
sed '${/^echo "Rebooting"$/d}'
```

All together:

```
curl -G website/bashscript.sh |
sed '${/^reboot$/d}' |
sed '${/^echo "Rebooting"$/d}' |
sudo bash
```

Comment: Amazing! Works like a charm. You could consider me a noob for syntax, why are you using $ and {} ? This looks like environment variable syntax to me, but that isn't true right?

Comment: @WD it is not, because `$` and `{}` are quoted with single quotes, which means, the shell will not evaluate them. They are passed to `sed` where they have a different meaning.

Answer (score -1):

Another variant with `grep`, which removes the unwanted commands in any line:

```
curl … | grep -vx 'echo "Rebooting"
reboot' | …
```